# Market Making Literature

Tags: market-making

I am not sure if this is the correct site to ask this, if not I apologize.

I have noticed some markets that lack in liquidity, and wonder why market makers in these markets cannot provide liquidity on the same scale as in other markets.

I would appreciate some links to academic literature, general market making books etc...So I can learn ways to provide liquidity to illiquid markets and various general market making techniques.

Comment: A standard on Market Microstructure is Harris: http://www.amazon.com/Trading-Exchanges-Market-Microstructure-Practitioners/dp/0195144708 . I'm not sure how it treats illiquid markets though.

Answer (score 4):

they are different books for quants addressing market microstructure

- [The Financial Mathematics of Market Liquidity](https://www.routledge.com/The-Financial-Mathematics-of-Market-Liquidity-From-Optimal-Execution-to/Gueant/p/book/9781498725477) 2016, by Guéant
- [Algorithmic and High-Frequency Trading](https://www.cambridge.org/ae/academic/subjects/mathematics/mathematical-finance/algorithmic-and-high-frequency-trading?format=HB&isbn=9781107091146) 2015, by Cartea, Jaimungal, Penalva
- [Market Microstructure in Practice](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/10739#t=aboutBook) 2nd edition 2018, L and Laruelle

In terms of papers: [Dealing with the Inventory Risk. A solution to the market making problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3115) 2012 by Guéant, L and Fernandez-Tapia is the final extension of [High-frequency trading in a limit order book](https://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Eavellane/HighFrequencyTrading.pdf) 2007 by Avellaneda and Stoikov.

Most of these papers do not directly address the question of *signals* and *toxicity metrics* that market makers are using. That for, I recommend Section 4 ("Evidence for the use of signals in trading") of [Incorporating Signals into Optimal Trading](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00847) 2018, by Neuman and L.